# Angular Material md-tabs with ui-router does not load initial tab

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-material

### Use case

I have an application that uses both, `angular-material` (v1.0.0) and `ui-router` (v0.2.15) and try to have a parent state that has child states which are shown within `md-tabs`/`md-tab`.

### Problem

I get it working but without the initial tab to be loaded. Only after clicking on the tabs, their state gets loaded.

### Code

```js
angular.module('demoApp', ['ui.router', 'ngMaterial'])

  .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('tabs', {
      url: '/tabs',
      template: '<div>' +
                '  <h1>Tabs View</h1>' +
                '  <md-tabs>' +
                '    <md-tab label="Foo" ui-sref="tabs.foo">' +
                '    </md-tab>' +
                '    <md-tab label="Bar" ui-sref="tabs.bar">' +
                '    </md-tab>' +
                '  </md-tabs>' +
                '  <md-content ui-view></md-content>' +
                '</div>'
    });
    $stateProvider.state('tabs.foo', {
      url: '/tabs/foo',
      template: 'Hello from Foo'
    });
    $stateProvider.state('tabs.bar', {
      url: '/tabs/bar',
      template: 'Hello from Bar'
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.when('/tabs', '/tabs/foo');
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tabs');
  })

;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="demoApp">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/v1.0.0/angular-material.css">

  <script src="//rawgit.com/angular/bower-angular/master/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//rawgit.com/angular/bower-angular-aria/master/angular-aria.js"></script>
  <script src="//rawgit.com/angular/bower-angular-animate/master/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="//rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/v1.0.0/angular-material.js"></script>
  <script src="//rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-router/master/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>
  
<body>
  
  <div ui-view></div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

[See my example at jsbin](https://jsbin.com/duxihifuzu/1/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: your jsbin doesn't seem to have any code in it..

Comment: @Gustav I updated the link, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you open the jsbin output to another window, so that you can watch the url, you will see that redirect to `/foo` doesn't work.

1. You have to configure first the `urlRouterProvider` and afterwards the `stateProvider`.
2. Also, from the ui-router [wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing):

   > When using url routing together with nested states the default
   >   behavior is for child states to append their url to the urls of each
   >   of its parent states.

So `/tabs/foo` has to become `/foo`, the same with `/tabs/bar`.

( if you want absolute urls you can use `url: '^/foo',` )

So your code becomes:

```
angular.module('demoApp', ['ui.router', 'ngMaterial'])

.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.when('/tabs', '/tabs/foo');
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tabs');

    $stateProvider.state('tabs', {
        url: '/tabs',
        template: '<div>' +
        '  <h1>Tabs View</h1>' +
        '  <md-tabs>' +
        '    <md-tab label="Foo" ui-sref="tabs.foo">' +
        '    </md-tab>' +
        '    <md-tab label="Bar" ui-sref="tabs.bar">' +
        '    </md-tab>' +
        '  </md-tabs>' +
        '  <md-content ui-view></md-content>' +
        '</div>'
    });
    $stateProvider.state('tabs.foo', {
        url: '/foo',
        template: 'Hello from Foo'
    });
    $stateProvider.state('tabs.bar', {
        url: '/bar',
        template: 'Hello from Bar'
    });
});
```

Working [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/lenodipika/1/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 1):

For more control, use a `controller` function on the parent state and set a default tab in a `angular.value()`

```
angular.module('demoApp', ['ui.router', 'ngMaterial'])
  .value('home_tab', 'tabs.foo')
  .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('tabs', {
      url: '/tabs',
      template: '<div>' +
                '  <h1>Tabs View</h1>' +
                '  <md-tabs>' +
                '    <md-tab label="Foo" ui-sref="tabs.foo">' +
                '    </md-tab>' +
                '    <md-tab label="Bar" ui-sref="tabs.bar">' +
                '    </md-tab>' +
                '  </md-tabs>' +
                '  <md-content ui-view></md-content>' +
                '</div>',
      controller: ['$state','home_tab', function($state, home_tab){$state.go(home_tab);}]
    });
    $stateProvider.state('tabs.foo', {
      url: '/tabs/foo',
      template: 'Hello from Foo'
    });
$stateProvider.state('tabs.bar', {
  url: '/tabs/bar',
  template: 'Hello from Bar'
});
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tabs');
```

})

Answer (score 0):

Check below js fiddle may be it solves your issue
    "https://jsfiddle.net/v8kk5fqq"